# Deleting a path from a canvas - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to delete a path from a canvas or make it transparent, I am using the following method to do this:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Path path=new Path();
//Add lines/arcs to path...
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));//tried SRC,CLEAR
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

But the path is being filled with black color, I want to make that transparent, is that possible?

Comment: You need to set xferMode to SRC_OUT

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. Try

```
paint.setAlpha(200);
```

you can insert values from 0 to 255.